# creating copy of file using file manager is not working for mac app

Tags: cocoa, nsfilemanager

I have a  file in one of the folder in my documents folder .I want to create a copy of that file in some other folder with some other name.The code I am using is

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSString * filePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/test/test1/%@%@%@",str,currentaudioTobPlayed,@".mp3"]];
NSString * filePath2 = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/test/test1/"]];

NSLog(@"filePat %@",filePath);
NSLog(@"filePath2 %@",filePath2);
NSLog(@"filePath2 %@",fileManager);

[fileManager copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:filePath2 error:NULL];
[fileManager release];
```

But this code is not working.Please help!

Comment: @Bavarious thanx! it worked.If you would have answered I would have voted u.Anyways thanx a alot

Comment: I’ve moved the comment to a full-blown answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In:

```
NSString * filePath2 = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/test/test1/"]];
```

you’re not specifying the destination file name: ~/Documents/test/test1 is a directory.

You could do this instead:

```
NSString *sourceName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.mp3",
    str, currentaudioTobPlayed];

// Choose the destination file name
NSString *destName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Copy of %@", sourceName];

NSString * filePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/test/test1/%@", sourceName]];

NSString * filePath2 = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/test/test1/%@", destName]];
// Replace Documents/test/test1 with another directory under home,
// or replace the whole string with an entirely different directory
```

Comment: @Swastik, please note the polite way to bring visibility to your questions is to [post a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty).